# Ember - Abort ajax request

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, ember.js, ember-data

I want to know how to abort a request.

For example, I issue `App.MyModel.find()` and later i want to cancel/abort it before it returns from server. I would expect something like this:

```
var res = App.MyModel.find();   //request sent to server
res.abort();                    // abort the request before completion
```

but this doesn't work - the returned object is a `promise` and there is neither `abort` nor `cancel` methods.

#### Clarification

I'm looking for how to call the [`abort`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-abort%28%29-method) method on the underlying `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Comment: just curious, what is your use case for that? why do you want to abort  it?

Comment: I want to abort it for cleanup when it is suddenly not needed before it is loaded. One possible case when user goes to another route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, when you call `App.MyModel.find()`, it's going to return you a `RecordArray`, not a `promise`.

From looking at the ember-data source code for RESTAdapter, I don't think there's a way to call abort on your `XMLHttpRequest` object.

You can implement your own RESTAdapter:

```
var myRESTAdapter = DS.Adapter.create({
  find: function (store, type, id) {
    var req = $.ajax({
      url:      type.url,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      context:  store,
      success:  function(response){
        this.load(type, id, response.data);
      }
    });
    req.abort();
  },
  findAll: function(store, type) {
    var req = $.ajax({
      url:      type.url,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      context:  store,
      success:  function(response){
        this.loadMany(type, response.data);
      }
    });
    req.abort();
  }
});
```

and call abort in `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Comment: Why are you calling `abort` after `ajax` call? Shouldn't it be stored instead?

Comment: I meant to show you a way to abort the request. It doesn't mean that you have to call abort after the ajax call. It means you can handle it in any way you want.

Comment: It doesn't help when trying to call abort outside of the original method.

Answer (score 8):

For those of you that wonder how to do it, here is how I acheived to cancel a jquery ajax request.

First, I defined a new method in my Application store that will call cancelQuery on my custom RESTAdapter.

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  cancelQuery: function(type){
    var adapter = this.adapterFor(this.modelFor(type).modelName);
    if(typeof adapter.cancelQuery === 'function'){
      adapter.cancelQuery();
    }
  }
});
```

In my custom RESTAdapter, I define that new function and override ajaxOptions like this :

```
App.YOURMODELAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  jqXHRs: [],
  ajaxOptions: function(url, type, hash) {
    // Get default AjaxOptions
    var ajaxOptions = this._super(url, type, hash);

    // If the function was defined in the DS.RESTAdapter object,
    // we must call it in out new beforeSend hook.
    var defaultBeforeSend = function(){};
    if(typeof ajaxOptions.beforeSend === 'function'){
      defaultBeforeSend = ajaxOptions.beforeSend;
    }
    ajaxOptions.beforeSend = function(jqXHR, settings){
      defaultBeforeSend(jqXHR, settings);
      this.jqXHRs.push(jqXHR); // Keep the jqXHR somewhere.
      var lastInsertIndex = this.jqXHRs.length - 1;
      jqXHR.always(function(){
        // Destroy the jqXHRs because the call is finished and 
        // we don't need it anymore.
        this.jqXHRs.splice(lastInsertIndex,1);
      });
    };

    return ajaxOptions;
  },
  // The function we call from the store.
  cancelQuery: function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.jqXHRs.length; i++){
      this.jqXHRs[i].abort();
    }
  }
});
```

Now, you can just call `cancelQuery` in the context of a controller.

```
this.store.cancelQuery('yourmodel');
```

Comment: This is a decent solution and works well in situations where you want to kill all outgoing connections, like during 'resetController' One issue is that aborting a jqXHR will actually trigger the fail handler and cause an error at the route. This can be alleviated by adding an `ajaxError` handler that checks the statusText != "abort" as described here: http://paulrademacher.com/blog/jquery-gotcha-error-callback-triggered-on-xhr-abort/

Comment: Nice catch ! If you do override the error handler, make sure to call the default error handler if the status != 'abort'. I used a similar trick with the `beforeSend` handler.

Comment: Yes indeed. As well, I'm not exactly sure but the `this.jqXHRs` might not work as expected if `beforeSend` is called outside of the adapter context. It might be prudent to create a closure for that outside the returned object. (e.g. `jqXHRs = this.jqXHRs` outside the `ajaxOptions.beforeSend` function.

Comment: Overriding error in the ajaxOptions function doesn't seem to do much since it will be overridden inside of the RESTAdapters ajax function.

Comment: Hi, this code is working with ember v1.8.1 and ember-data beta19. They made major change since then so if it's not working on your version, maybe you can take the code and adapt it to your need.

Answer (score -1):

Http is request-response interaction.Once the request is sent,it can't be canceled.You can fine some way to ignore the response from the server instead;

Comment: Please see my clarification.

Comment: The Promise object (RSVP) should allow for a way to cancel the request and trigger a reject or failure event.

Comment: Lol, what do you mean a HTTP request can't be aborted? Why do you assume the request makes it to the server in the first place? Also, you can definitely cancel a HTTP request even while it is actively being processed on the server (think streaming). The OP question is very legit for cleanup, user abort, or route switching / controller reset scenarios.