# How do I ignore an aborted Ajax request error in Ember 1.13.x/2.0?

Tags: ajax, ember.js, ember-data

I am canceling Ajax requests in my adapter under certain circumstances (I referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24004775/977044) answer when writing my code) and previously I had used the `ajaxError` hook (code below) to ignore 'abort' errors caused by aborting the Ajax requests. What I was doing was looking at the `responseText` and comparing it to 'abort', and if it was an 'abort', I ignored it so it didn't actually throw an error/show up in the console.

In Ember 1.13.9 though, I am of course getting a deprecation warning for ajaxError as it is going away. The problem is, I'm not sure what to use to do this now. I tried using `handleResponse`, but it looks like `handleResponse` never gets called if the request is aborted. It's possible I was doing something wrong, but I put a console.log in `handleResponse` and it never printed anything when the requests were canceled. Is `handleResponse` the right way to go, and am I missing something? If not, is there some other hook I can use?

```
ajaxError: function(jqXHR, responseText, errorThrown){
  if(responseText != 'abort'){
    this._super(jqXHR, responseText, errorThrown);
  }
}
```